# PHP .htaccess removing .php extension and language directory to parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm looking for a regulair expression for a `.htaccess` file inside my PHP server.

What I want is that it detects the language from the first directory as parameter:

- nl
- en
- be
- de

Any other options must be treated as a directory or filename. The language must be given as parameter without corrupting any other parameters.

Also I want the last `/` replaced by `.php`.

Some examples:

```
host.com/nl/index/ -> host.com/index.php?lang=nl
host.com/de/test/abc/ -> host.com/test/abc.php?lang=de
host.com/be/a/b/c/?t=23 -> host.com/a/b/c.php?lang=be&t=23
```

Is this possible? I can't get it to work, I hope someone will help me out!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule >>> requested expression and replacing pattern <<<
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do the language directories (nl etc.) actually exist?

Comment: @Ravi Well, for now. But I want to get rid of those. If you meant if there would exists any directory called nl, de, be or en: no, I will prevent that, especially if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})(/.+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

Regexes are easiest to interpret by considering a piece at a time. Let's break that down:

- `^` - start of URL
- `/` - match first slash
- `([a-z]{2})` - match and capture 2 letters (goes into the `$1` variable)
- `(` - begin capture group (goes into `$2`)
- `/` - match a slash
- `.+` - match zero or more characters
- `)` - end capture group (`$2`)
- `/?` - match an OPTIONAL end slash of the "file path" (but don't capture it)
- `$` - end of URL

So, you're capturing two things:

**1**. the **language** (capture group `$1`):

```
([a-z]{2})
```

**2**. the **file path**, starting with a slash (capture group `$2`), followed by an optional slash:

```
(/.+)/?
```

Finally, the `QSA` flag at the end appends your original query string (if there was one) to your rewritten URL. If you'd like to make your regex match case-insensitive (i.e. allow URLs like `host.com/NL/index/`), you can add the `NC` flag too: `[QSA,NC]`. Alternatively, you could explicitly allow capital letters by using `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[a-z]` in your regex.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and working answer. I basically already understood regular expressions, but this one was a bit too hard for me since I don't know how it coöperates which the .htaccess script. Can you tell me which kind of regex it uses? Also my index file won't work anymore.

Comment: Also it can't figure out why this is working with multiple directories. Does the `(/.+)` capture more than one `/` for the `.`? Seems weird to me.

Comment: Think of them separately. The `/` has nothing to do with the `.`. `/` matches a slash. `.` matches "any character". `+` means "one or more of the previous". So, `/.+` matches a slash followed by one or more characters (ANY characters). That means it would match `/hello` or `/hello/` or `/hello/how/are/you` or even `/hello$'()/whatever/`. If you'd like to make that rule more restrictive, instead of `.`, you could use `[\w/]`, which matches any word character OR slash. so `/[\w/]+` would match `/hello` and `/hello/how` and `/hello/how/are/` but not `/hello/hfo$'()/`

Comment: @sgroves Thanks, that part sounds as easy as you say it is. But how can it match the last `/` while it should already being matched by the `.`?

Comment: @Tim short answer: that's just how the regex engine works. because i explicitly tell the regex to match a `/` AFTER the `.+`, the `+` won't match the last `/` in the string. it will, however, match any previous slashes because it's a greedy quantifier.

@anubhava correct - this answer does not try to match the query string

Comment: Thanks for your input and your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+?)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What are the options doing and why must the base directory be set the `/`? Also, could you provide me a link where I can get information about `[L,QSA,NC]`?

Comment: Check this official guide: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html Pls try out this answer and see if this works. If it does I will add more explanation answering all your questions.

Comment: `RewriteBase` sets the path to which `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is relative. (By default, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is relative to your *file system root*, which is almost definitely not what you want. That's why people use `RewriteBase /`. Here, `/` is the root of the directory containing your `.htaccess` file.